# If earth stopped spinning how much heavier would 1kg feel

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, earth, centripetal-force

My girlfriend seems to think if the earth stops spinning we will all fall off

However, she did spark my imagination, due to centripetal force things must feel lighter then they otherwise would on an non spinning earth

Firstly, is this correct, secondly, what would the net effect be in ratio to a 1 kg weight

**Update**

I'm also wondering if there would be any relativistic affects that would contribute +/-

**Update 2**

An equatorial position would be adequate

Comment: You can assure your girflriend that she is not at any risk falling off anytime soon. What did you try to solve the problem?

Comment: On Wikipedia you can find the formula for the centripetal force: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force. For your purpose the most convenient form may be $F=mr4\pi^2/T^2$, with $m=1kg$ and $T=24h*(3600s/h)=86400s$. If we put this into the equation, we get $F=r*5.288*10^{-9}N/m$. So now all you need is an estimate for $r$, the distance between you and the Earth's axis in meters. This will give you the size of the centripetal force at your location. Please not, that this force is NOT pointing to the zenith, unless you are standing on the equator.

Comment: Comment to the question (v2): Note that the shape of Earth without spinning would be different. This would contribute to the change in little-$g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a back-of-the-envelope calculation..
$a_{\rm centrifugal} = R \Omega^2 = 6.4 \times 10^6 \times \left( 2\pi/86400 \right)^2 \sim 0.03 \;\rm{m}\, \rm{s^{-2}}$ is about 0.3% of the gravity of Earth. Of course, it would depend on the latitude you live at.

Answer (score 0):

if the earth stops spinning , the angular speed of earth would become zero. nevertheless nobody will fall.as the effective acceleration would become g m/s. the centripetal acceleration would be zero,in such situation the weight  measured will be same on any colatitude of earth.